# Loading multiple feeds at the same time with simplexml?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have multiple feeds, how do i load them at the same time with simplexml

```
http://www.site1.com/feed
http://www.site2.com/feed
http://www.site3.com/feed
...
http://www.site20.com/feed


$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
```

Comment: Is this PHP? What XML library are you using?

Comment: I don't understand. What is keeping you from loading them one after one? What do you want to achieve as the end result?

Comment: I was going to reply to your previous question with a long, nice and useful answer on how to do it, and you deleted it. How nice is that?

Comment: I thought no one knew the answer:( Want me to ask it again? The question with the code and the rss parsing?

Comment: Well, the question required more than 5 minutes to answer -.- I wasted my time there

Comment: Want me to ask it again? The answer would be very helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load multiple things in PHP you have to create a loop.

Example:

```
<?php
$feeds = ('http://www.site1.com/feed', 'http://www.site2.com/feed', '..');

foreach($feeds as $feed)
{
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
}
?>
```

Comment: How can I echo for example the Title ?

Comment: please write.. How I echo for example